MacOS set file Modified Time with timezone
tl;dr on Mac OS, I want to set a file's filesystem Modification Time using a datetimestamp that includes a timezone offset, e.g. -0700. touch and SetFile do not support timezone offsets. Is there a different CLI tool?

On Mac OS 14, I want to set a file's Modification Time. The datetimestamp is 2023-12-15T14:34:48.273-0800. Substring -0800 is the timezone offset.
touch
Using touch, this fails
touch -c -d '2023-12-15T14:34:48.273-0800' ./file
touch: out of range or illegal time specification: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:SS[.frac][tz]

touch documentation reads

-d Change the access and modification times to the specified date time instead of the current time of day.
The argument is of the form “YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:SS[.frac][tz]” (ISO 8601)
where the letters represent the following:
tz      An optional letter Z indicating the time is in UTC.
Otherwise, the time is assumed to be in local time.
Local time is affected by the value of the TZ environment variable.

So touch only accepts substring Z as a timezone.
SetFile
SetFile documentation reads

-d date  Set the creation date, where date is
a string of the form: "mm/dd/[yy]yy [hh:mm:[:ss] [AM | PM]]"

So SetFile will does not process any timezone substring.
Summary
Is there a CLI tool for Mac OS that will take a datetimestamp string 2023-12-15T14:34:48.273-0800 and set the file Modification Time?

During view in macOs 10.11 AM or PM setting is not taken into account in Quick Preview or in Quick Look, in some Terminal ones and in forth view of Finder where found.

Does this achieve what you wanted?
TZ=+08:00 touch -c -d '2023-12-15T14:34:48.273' ./file

